# How to get a version of UI5 framework within the controller?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I want to retrieve an UI5 version (e.g. `1.97.0-SNAPSHOT`) inside of controller. The simplest way is to get a value of `sap.ui.version`, but it's a global variable, which I want to avoid.

I thought, [`sap.ui.VersionInfo`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/module:sap/ui/VersionInfo) would be a right choice, but looking at its API, I can't find any method, related to the retrieval of the UI5 version.

I also checked the controller's internals (not too deep) and `sap.ui.Device`, but no version number.

How can I retrieve the UI5 framework version without using a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **OpenUI5**, require `sap/ui/core/Core` and get an instance of [`sap/base/util/Version`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/base/util/Version) via `Core.getConfiguration().getVersion()`.

In case of **SAPUI5**, however, the patch version is not always same as the version of SAPUI5 core (`sap.ui.core`) since SAPUI5-exclusive libraries may contain patches in addition to OpenUI5 libraries. See this [graphic SAPUI5 library patch versions (e.g. v1.96)](https://ui5.sap.com/1.96/patchinfo.html). To get the correct SAPUI5 version reliably, require the module `sap/ui/VersionInfo`. Its [method `load()`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/VersionInfo#methods/sap/ui/VersionInfo.load) will return a promise that resolves with an object - [same as  `https://<host>/resources/sap-ui-version.json`](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-version.json) - containing all information about the current framework including its version.

```js
// VersionInfo required from "sap/ui/VersionInfo"
// VersionUtil required from "sap/base/util/Version"

// Within an async function:
const { version } = await VersionInfo.load();
const versionUtil = new VersionUtil(version);
```

As you can see, it's also possible to combine the retrieved version string with the [module `sap/base/util/Version`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/base/util/Version) which provides methods such as `getMajor()`, `getMinor()`, `getPatch()`, `compareTo(...)`, `inRange(...)`, etc.

See section "SAPUI5 Version vs. OpenUI5 Version (Core Version)" from the documentation topic *[Versioning and Maintenance of SAPUI5](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f021426f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*.

---

#### ⚠️ Known issue

When using the module `sap/ui/VersionInfo` in a **standalone** UI5 app (e.g. built with `ui5 build self-contained -a`), the top `version` value from the generated `resources/sap-ui-version.json` is the **app version** instead of the version of the framework. [There is currently no reliable way for standalone SAPUI5 apps to determine the correct patch version](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3386#issuecomment-1059432000).

See the issue [SAP/ui5-tooling#353](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/353).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like to be a solution, although it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Perhaps, I'll stay with `sap.ui.version` :)

Comment: @Mike the `sap.ui.version` refers to UI5 _core version_ (i.e. OpenUI5 version) only. If you're using **SAPUI5**, the patch version number might differ from the patch version of `sap.ui.version`. E.g. Visit https://ui5.sap.com/1.94.1/. Entering `sap.ui.version` in the console returns `"1.94.0"` (== core version) and not `"1.94.1"`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point! Thus, only `sap.ui.VersionInfo` seems to be a reliable source of the version info. Although, I assumed I could reach an UI5 core version somewhere inside of the controller.

Comment: @Mike More information about the versioning in SAPUI5: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/04/01/ui5ers-buzz-49-the-ui5-tooling-and-sapui5-the-next-step/